# How do I verify the orthogonal decomposition theorem for a specific matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I verify the orthogonal decomposition theorem for $$A = \pmatrix{2 & 1 & 1 & \\ -1 & -1 & 0 \\ -2 & -1 & -1}$$

In other words, I want to show that for all $A \in R^{m \times n}$,

$$R(A)^{\perp} = N(A^T)$$

and

$$N(A)^{\perp} = R(A^T)$$

Comment: I have changed the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if $y$ is in $N(A^\top),$  then $A^\top y = 0$ which is the same as $$y^\top A = 0 \tag 1$$  you can interpret equation $(1)$ as saying that $y$ is orthogonal to every column of $A.$ which means $y \in R(A)^\perp$ we have shown that $$ N(A^\top) \subset R(A)^\perp $$

all the steps can be reversed, and that gives you $N(A^\top) =R(A)^\perp.$ replacing $A$ by $A^\top$ should give you the other result.